# IoT cloud in salesforce pricing

Tags: licenses, userlicense, iot

I have been trying to get the licensing and cost structure for IoT cloud in Salesforce.

Anyone got any idea around same, please let me know.

Comment: That is something that you really have to talk to the Salesforce Account Executives about, each organisation using SFDC will have one or partner orgs usually have contact with them on the sales side.

Comment: Is this even for sale already? I haven't seen anything concrete yet.

Comment: Ya that is what even I am trying to figure out. If there is any pricing updates or demo org to be used around same.

Answer (score 5):

As of W'18, Salesforce has split IoT offerings into two products: IoT Scale and IoT Explorer.

IoT Scale is a custom application cluster on top of Kafka running on AWS. This is what was previously referred to as Thunder and then IoT Cloud. These clusters are meant to handle billions of events per day and allow for some amazingly complicated telemetry processing. It's very expensive but also really needed for huge deployments.

IoT Explorer is new as of W'18, and you can try it in developer editions. Hooray! IoT Explorer provides the same orchestration engine as IoT Scale but has more limited input processing.

Salesforce recommends starting with IoT Explorer, and then working with Salesforce directly when you are pushing limits -- 500k platform events per day.

IoT Explorer starts at $6000/month and is based on number of events, not users.

Comment: Update: IoT Scale has been deprecated. However, there is now an IoT Enterprise, which is the same architecture as IoT Explorer but with larger limits on devices and platform events.